# Kotlin Room Query to return entity values grouped by another value

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I ran into a problem while trying to fetch a combined data from Room. This is my entity :

```
@Entity(tableName = "liquids_table")
class Liquid (
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
 val id : Int,
 val liquidName : String,
 val liquidAmount : Int,
 val dateOfConsumption : Long
)
```

I want to retrieve all Liquids in DB grouped by their names. This is the Query I am using.

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM liquids_table WHERE dateOfConsumption >= :dayStart AND dateOfConsumption <= :dayEnd GROUP BY liquidName")
fun getDailyEntries(dayStart: Long, dayEnd: Long): LiveData<List<Liquid>?>
```

This works, and I am able to retrive all the Liquid entities grouped by their liquidName. However, when I want to retrieve their liquidAmount, this only returns the amount of the first entry with the given name.

So If I entered:

100 ml Coffe,
200 ml Water,
500 ml Coffee

in that order, I get returned 100ml Coffee, 200ml Water. I want to however receive 600ml Coffee, 200ml Water.

If you could help out on how I can fix my query for this, it would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to retrieve all Liquids in DB grouped by their names.

**GROUP BY** returns a single row per **GROUP** and thus 1 Coffee row for the 2 Coffee rows.

With the exception of the column(s) that make up the **GROUP**, without using an aggregate function(s) you will get an arbitrary value (a value from one of the columns).

As such it sounds like you want to use the **[SUM](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc)** aggregate function to add all the liquidAmount values for each group.

As such you appear to want `SUM(liquidAmount)` and to appease Room to give the result column a name that correlates with the val in the type you are extracting the data into i.e. liquidAmount (otherwise the column name will be `sum(liquidAmount)` and Room wouldn't know what to do).

So you want to use `sum(liquidAmount ) AS liquidAmount` as such you cannot use * for all columns. As this will then not include the other columns you then want to include the other columns. Again noting that arbirtary values will be used for the other columns except the liquidName column (which is the same for all the rows in the GROUP).

As such you could use :-

```
@Query("SELECT id,liquidname, sum(liquidAmount) AS liquidAmount, dateOfConsumption FROM liquids_table WHERE dateOfConsumption >= :dayStart AND dateOfConsumption <= :dayEnd GROUP BY liquidName")
fun getDailyEntries(dayStart: Long, dayEnd: Long): LiveData<List<Liquid>?>
```

- **id** will be an arbitrary value (and will effectively not be of much use)
- **dateOfConsumption** will be an arbitrary value.

You may wish to consider using other aggregate functions for the other arbitrary values.

e.g. you could use `min(id) AS id` instead of just **id** to ensure that the id was the lowest id (max if you want the highest)

You may wish to refer to [SQLite - Built-in Aggregate Functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) and also [SQLite - SELECT - Simple SELECT Processing](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#simple_select_processing) (especially 3. Generation of the set of result rows.)

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for the explanation as well!